# Picasa-like image viewer for Ubuntu (to flip quickly through large numbers of images)

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, image-viewers

I am looking for an image viewer that allows me to flip through a huge number of images (~10000 images) very quickly so that minute changes are visible. I need this for image classification and testing. Picasa allows me to do it perfectly with easy back and forth switching so that I can identify changes in illumination, small movements, and large movements. Making it into a movie using `ffmpeg` is not an option as I require the individual images.

For example, say I observed between images 24 and 25 there is an Illumination change and I want to experiment on those two frames.

The problem with the existing image viewers in Ubuntu is that they are very slow compared to Picasa while moving back and forth and hence is inconvenient. Also, I noticed a tendency that after 10.jpeg, the default image viewer in Ubuntu switches to 11000.jpeg. And before 10.jpeg, it passes like 10999 -> 1099 -> 10.

Is there any such image viewer which works like Picasa? Like really smooth while moving between pictures and also in order. Please note that I do not intend to edit any of the images only move through them very fast or at least fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Googles Picasa in Ubuntu by wine. HQ [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/picasa)